# Integration of area

Tags: integration

For $0<h<R$ we have the surface
$$S_{h,R}=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2, z\geq h\}$$
How does this suface look? What is the area of $S_{h,R}$ and what is $\int_{S_{h,R}} z^2dS$?

I don't really know how to integrate here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Do you recognize $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ as a sphere with radius $R$? With that, how does $z\geq h$ restrict the sphere?

When doing the surface integral, $dS=\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}  dxdy$ where $z_x,z_y$ are partial derivatives of $z$.

From the equation of the sphere, can you derive $z$ in terms of $x,y$ and write down the double integral? You might eventually solve the double integral using polar coordinate.

Comment: How do I transform these to polar coordinates then?

Comment: @TonyStrong: Let $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$, where $r$ is the radius of the disk the original region projected onto $xy$ plane. You should think about what that is.

Comment: Is it that $r=R$?

Comment: @TonyStrong: No. What's the effect of $z\geq h$? Try to draw a picture.

Comment: I cant really visualize this